# Gathering user data on a Google Add-on to determine usage levels appropriate for monetization

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets Add-on about which I'd like to determine feasibility of monetizing. To do this I'd like to see frequency level of users; users per domain as well as how often they use the add-on.

I've read a bit about properties in the documentation, and I'm pretty sure that is at the heart of what I need to work on to start getting this data. My question is about routing that to a form I can use to crunch numbers.

I have considered just having the Properties Service send the user's email and date generated in the Add-on (not the current date, but the date for the content generated). Once that gets sent to a spreadsheet in my drive, I can use a script bound to the spreadsheet to determine if the user has been logged yet. If so, we move the date to the row for that user. If not, we create a new entry. I can also have the script order users based on domain so I can see domains with heavier usage.

I've never done this before, so I'm looking to see if I'm thinking in the right direction or if I'm overlooking something.

Comment: I think that it makes sense to collect data locally, and then transmit the usage data externally less often.  Your Terms of Service should explain what the user is agreeing to in terms of collecting usage data, and your Privacy Policy should explain what data you collect, how it's used, whether you share it or not, and how you store it.  If you are not collecting personal data, then make that point.  Collecting and transmitting usage data is possible, and can be done in multiple different ways.  How you export the data could depend upon permissions you want to ask for.  Eg. External Request.

Comment: Thank you Alan. That was a good explanation that gave me something relatively simple to implement, which I did. Every time the user uses one of two functions in the add-on, it sends info to two cells in a hidden sheet. Once seven pieces of data are collected (a week), it sends it to a sheet I own. My only concern is that users can still unhide that sheet and hack usage data. This is why I like the idea of sending direct to my sheet. Do you have any suggestions on this? I'm not sure range protections will work. @Alan Wells

Comment: You can save the data to Properties Service, Document properties.  Properties Service can only save data as a string, so if the data being saved is an object, you must first use `JSON.stringify(obj)` before setting the value.  If you don't use `JSON.stringify(obj)` before setting the value, and the value is an object, then it will automatically be converted to a string, but it's not converted in the same way as `JSON.stringify(obj)`.